# How to create database driver independent of database types

Tags: database, database-design

I want to create a custom database driver that will be independent of database types like `SQL Server`, `SQL LITE` or `MDB`. Please give some ideas on how to implement this.

Comment: In what language? In Java there is already [tag:jdbc] standard, but it won't help you with different SQL dialects, you need higher abstraction level.

Comment: Please ask a concrete question, where the answer is likely to be specific, rather than asking for ideas.

Comment: I need to create in using C#. is there any such drivers in C# that can use different DB types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very general.  I'll be surprised if you get any detailed programming tips concerning the architecture of a database independent database server.

As a very general thing, I'd recommend that you look into a feature that has been embedded in MS Access for over 12 years.  It's table links.

Table links allow an MS Access database+application to include tables or views from other databases as if they were views in the Access database.  It does this by accessing the DBMS server that knows how to operate on the foreign database, using some mechanism like ODBC.

In this setup, the client (the local Access application) talks to the local MS Access server, which talks to the foreign database server, which talks to the database.

I realize this isn't quite what you were asking for.  But you need to understand it before you embark on some architecture that bypasses the foreign DBMS server.